# Finding the source of non malloc C++ memory leaks on Windows

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, com

Is there anything that I can use to detect all types of memory use in an application, including COM and other non-malloc allocations? Even just the DLL where the allocations are made would help.

We have an application which is showing constant memory growth of 400 MByte/day on just one of our customer sites, but not anywhere else.

I've tried using Microsoft's gflags / umdh, but out of 800 MByte / 2 days growth, umdh showed only 17 MByte difference, which is a normal minute to minute memory change.

Having run some tests, I can see that umdh does not detect COM leaks. I've also tried Intel Inspector on a test program that leaks via COM but that doesn't detect them either.

There are 3 possible places the growth can be coming from, our code, 3rd party libraries, and the customers application monitoring software which embeds its dlls in the application. I've examined the process memory in Windbg and can see that the data in it is not generated directly by our code, so my suspicion is that the growth is occurring in one of the DLLs that we have no control over.

Comment: I beleive any profiler should help, like Deleaker.

Comment: If you're using VS, there's a built in memory profiler. Just note that it makes your program run slow af.

Comment: From COM, you have IMallocSpy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-imallocspy

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks, that looks like it should do the trick for COM allocations.